# How to mix down 2 audio file into one programmatically on Mac

Tags: macos, audio

I have 2 audio file, and want to mix down them into one file programmatically on my Mac.

I would like to write a script using a command line tool, or write a application using an audio lib. But I cannot find a command line tool or an audio lib to do that. Does anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ffmpeg`. I installed mine with `homebrew` which makes life easier on a Mac. Then you can do the actual mix like this:

```
ffmpeg -i track1.mp3 -i track2.m4a -filter_complex amerge output.mp3
```

another option is:

```
ffmpeg -i track1.mp3 -i track2.m4a -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest output.mp3
```

Or you can use `sox`, like this:

```
sox -m a.mp3 b.mp3 output.mp3
```

Note: Mixing down AC/DC with ABBA to test what I am suggesting does not produce a goood sound!!!